# Como utilizar @import em um arquivo CSS?

Tags: css, css3

Dentro de um arquivo estilo.css estou usando a opção `@import url()` para chamar outro arquivo `CSS`.

Por exemplo:

```
@import url("/css/fonts.css")
```

Tanto o arquivo quanto o caminho estão corretos e mesmo assim não consigo importar esse `CSS`.

- Onde pode está o erro?
- Nesse caso,qual a melhor maneira de usar o `@import`?

Comment: Você já verificou se o arquivo está realmente sendo atulizado e livre de cache?

Comment: o seu @import é a primeira linha do seu .css? Sem nada antes, nem mesmo comentários ? Se você puder colar o começo do seu .css, seria melhor

Comment: O caminho está realmente certo?

Comment: @woliveirajr putz cara fui um ignorante agora, existia uma linha de comentário antes e não sabia que isso influenciava troquei a posição e funcionou, grato.

Comment: @HeltonSS legal que funcionou. Coloquei o comentário como resposta, assim voce pode aceitar e ficará mais fácil para os futuros visitantes da sua pergunta saberem qual foi a resposta que ajudou.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A linha do `@import` tem que ser a primeira no seu arquivo .CSS. Se você inserir qualquer informação antes (por exemplo, comentários), o `@import` falhará.

No máximo, você poderá ter um

```
<style>
    @import....
</style>
```

antes do seu `@import`.

Comment: Lembrando que o '@import' deve vir DEPOIS do '@charset' (se existir um).

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_import_rule.asp

Answer (score 9):

Recomendo que o `@import` seja colocado logo após `@charset "UTF-8";`.

Depois você deve especificar o caminho da fonte fornecido no *Google Fonts*, logo após a fonte estará instalada e pronta para ser utilizada. Importante ressaltar que temos que utilizar o nome específico que o site fornece para funcionar corretamente. No meu exemplo, usei a fonte `Titillium` pelo [Google Web Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/).Veja:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web');
h1 {
font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}
```

Vale lembrar que o `@import` é um elemento `CSS`, então pode ficar dentro de uma tag `<style>` no `head` do seu `HTML`. Nesse exemplo, usei a fonte `Dancing Script` pelo *Google Fonts*, o código fica assim:

```
<style type="text/css">
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script);
</style>
```

Obs: Além da segurança de usar fontes do *Google Web Fonts*, temos também a facilidade, sem precisar fazer download de nada, apenas copiando o caminho da fonte desejada que já está hospedada nos servidores do google e especificando o seu nome no seu arquivo `CSS`.

Refencia:

- [Como usar WebFonts no E-mail Marketing](https://templateria.com/blog/templates/como-usar-webfonts-no-email-marketing/)

Answer (score 3):

Como já mencionado pelo @woliveirajr, o `@import` deve estar na primeira linha do arquivo.

Só um comentário: lembre-se considerar que o uso do `@import` pode  trazer um impacto negativo na performance do seu site. De acordo com [um post de Steve Sounders](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/), ao contrário do tag `<link>`, se você tem múltiplos comandos `@import` em sequência, eles podem não ser carregados em paralelo no momento em que a sua página é aberta.

Outra vantagem de se usar o `<link>` em vez do `@import` é que você pode especificar também o tipo do atributo `media` (print, screen, etc), ou [definir folhas de estilo preferidas ou alternativas](http://alistapart.com/article/alternate).

Answer (score 1):

Você não deve usar /css/arquivo.css, utilize: css/arquivo.css sem o "/" na frente do nome da pasta.
Sendo assim, ficaria: @import url("css/fonts.css") e caso ele esteja na mesma pasta, basta usar: @import url("fonts.css")

Answer (score 1):

Usando no Joomla esse modelo.

```
/*comment pode vir antes */

@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
```

Lembrando que o `@import` é a primeira linha antes de qualquer seletor. Mas pode haver comentários antes dela que funcionará também.